# pytest selenium output flooded with debug logs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, logs

### What's Happening

I'm writing acceptance tests with selenium-python and pytest on python 2.7.
Whenever a test fails the CLI output is **flooded** with `debug` output under `---captured log call---` *for every failed test.*

**Example**

```
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "valueFx"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-1'}}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-1/click {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9                                                                                              dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-1"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': None}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-28'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "rightValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-29'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftFXMove"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-30'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "RightFXMove"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-31'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    GET http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0c                                                                                              9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-28/text {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9d                                                                                              d090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-28"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': u''}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-28'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    GET http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0c                                                                                              9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-28/text {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9d                                                                                              d090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-28"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': u''}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-28'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    GET http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0c                                                                                              9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-28/text {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9d                                                                                              d090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-28"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': u''}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-28'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    GET http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0c                                                                                              9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-28/text {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9d                                                                                              d090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-28"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': u''}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-28'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    GET http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0c                                                                                              9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-28/text {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9d                                                                                              d090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-28"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': u''}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-28'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    GET http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0c                                                                                              9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-28/text {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9d                                                                                              d090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-28"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': u''}
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0                                                                                              c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d689                                                                                              23e9c1f", "value": "leftValue"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': {u'ELEMENT': u'0.40203467536832127-28'}                                                                                              }
remote_connection.py       480 DEBUG    GET http://127.0.0.1:52030/session/3561e266d0c                                                                                              9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f/element/0.40203467536832127-28/text {"sessionId": "3561e266d0c9d                                                                                              d090e0a4d68923e9c1f", "id": "0.40203467536832127-28"}
remote_connection.py       567 DEBUG    Finished Request {u'status': 0, u'sessionId':                                                                                               u'3561e266d0c9dd090e0a4d68923e9c1f', u'value': u'-110459.82231227'}
```

*That's for 1 test failure!*
When I have N failures, this `debug` output is multiplied for every test. Compared to the 10-20 lines pytest outputs showing my failed test and the exception raised, this is both needlessly verbose and time-consuming to search through.

Running in quiet mode doesn't remove this output either.

```
pytest tests/acceptance/pricers/test_fxfwd.py -q
```

or running with multiple flags of `-q`...

## How then do I remove this debug output or otherwise prevent it from being displayed for failed tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confirm this in your pytest.ini like this.

```
[pytest] 
log_print = False
```

You can also add log_format options to send different log levels to different files , you will at some point want to see those logs.

For the full options and more background the docs are here
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html

If the file is not present, add pytest.ini in the root directory of your test suite.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! (I didn't even have a pytest config file).